# How can I align my buttons so that they stay in the same line?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align my btns to be center and stay in the same row, and I'm not sure how will I accomplish that.

---

[image]

This is what I have :

What We do
      Subtext for what we do</span> -->

```
  {{-- Left --}}
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="feature-img"> <span class="fa fa-graduation-cap fa-5x"></span> </div>
    <h3>Tutti.ed</h3>
    <p style="text-align: justify;" >Tutti.ed is an educational software framework that serves as the backbone for robust digital learning products.

      Your brand, your content, your instructional vision... our technology.

      View our gallery to see sample products.

      <br><br><a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="/tutti-ed">Learn more </a>

    </p>
  </div>


  {{-- Middle --}}
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="feature-img"> <span class="fa fa-code fa-5x"></span> </div>
    <h3>Tutti.dev</h3>
    <p style="text-align: justify;" >Tutti.dev makes the work of software professionals easier by facilitating all stages of the software development lifecycle.

      Tutti.dev was created by developers, for developers. We set out to create the toolset we always wished we had to make our work easier.

      <br><br><a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="/tutti-dev">Learn more </a>

    </p>
  </div>


  {{-- Rigth --}}
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="feature-img"> <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-5x"></span>
    </div>
    <h3>Services</h3>
    <p style="text-align: justify;" >Aveniros can help your company in every or any phase of development.

      We provide tools and development expertise to every project to ensure a successful launch.

      <br><br><a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="/services">Learn more </a>

    </p>
  </div>


</div>
```

Any hints / helps /suggestions will be much appreciated !

It will be great you guys can give any suggestion based on what I have.

Comment: Where are your buttons in the code? There's no "Learn More" button in there

Comment: Pasted in wrong block of code - sorry ab that. Thanks for asking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat your row with two boxes. Now, add your buttons in the boxes and it will works.

```
  <section class="page-block" id="features">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row page-header">
             <h2>What We do</h2>
            <span>Subtext for what we do</span>
         </div>
      <div class="row features">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">          
            <h3>Tutti.dev</h3>          
            <p style="text-align: justify;" >blah blah </p>   
      </div>     
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">        
          <h3>Tutti.ed</h3>
          <p style="text-align: justify;" >blah blah </p>     
     </div>
   </div>
  <div class="row features">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <button>My Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
       <button>My Button</button>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First to center the button - Apply `text-align: center;` to the columns (the buttons containing element).

Second, you need them to stick to the bottom. Wrap the 3 columns into a row with `position: relative;` and a `clearfix`.

Then for the buttons `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`. Add some padding at the bottom of your columns that prevents the buttons appearing over the column content.

Hope this helps!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.row {
  position: relative;
}
.col {
  width: 33.333%;
  background: aliceblue;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
div p {
  text-align: justify;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <p> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
  <div class="col">
  <p> It has survived not only five centuries.</p>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Can be achieved without the `.clearfix` by using `overflow: hidden;`

[Pen using `overflow: hidden;`](http://codepen.io/matthewelsom/pen/BNLXBm).

Comment: Good answer, but one thing I'd suggest is not to use a clearfix if you don't really have to. Instead of using a clearfix you can set `.row` to `overflow:hidden` and it will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: thanks @gautsch - I have learned something here too! Added to my answer.